# can i set node environment variable in Object format in Azure

Tags: node.js, azure, environment-variables

In my nodejs project during development I'm using `.env` file for using environment variables

and one of the variables is set to be like this

```
varName = {"key1": "value2", "key2":"value2"}
```

can i set the same variable with same format in azure environment variable ??
does azure accept it ?

please note: that i have no access to azure and i am only allowed to work locally on my machine where my code is working fine

Comment: you will have to stringify and set and then in your config file you can parse.

Comment: That's for sure , But is it ok to be like that in azure ?
Thanks for your replay

Comment: if you want to keep it like that you can as it's just a string so azure won't create any problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you can set the same variable with same format in azure environment variable, as the figure below. I added a new application setting in the tab `Configuration` of Azure WebApp on Azure portal.

[image]

Then, I moved to the Kudu console of the Azure WebApp to inspect whether the `TEST` variable with a json string exists via the code `node -e "console.log(process.env)"` as the figure below.

[image]

And I found it as the figure below.

[image]

As @AZ_ said, the `TEST` variable value is a string, you need to use `JSON.parse` to convert it to JSON object.

```
var test = JSON.parse(process.env.TEST);
console.log(test.key1);
```

[image]